# Find angle between two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, normed-spaces, inner-products

> For the inner product space $M_{2\times2} (\Bbb{C})$, with inner product $\langle A,B\rangle = \operatorname{tr}(AB^*)$, find the angle between
>
> $$A=\begin{bmatrix}2+i&1\\-1&0\end{bmatrix} $$
>
> $$B=\begin{bmatrix}3-2i&1+i\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}$$

I tried to use $$\cos(z)=\frac{\langle A,B\rangle}{\|A\|\|B\|}=\frac{5+6i}{4\sqrt{7}}$$ but how can I find the angle? is it supposed to be a real number?

Comment: For that matter, with the standard (complex) inner product on ${\bf C}^2$, how do you find the angle between two vectors?

Comment: See my answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2079945/what-is-the-angle-between-those-two-matrices-over-mathbbc/2080001#2080001)

Answer (score 0):

The [inverse of  the cos function is defined for complex arguments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions) as well.

$$\operatorname{arccos}(z)=-i\operatorname{Log}\left(iz+\sqrt{1-z^2}\right).$$

Where Log is the so called [complex logarithm defined as](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm)

$$\operatorname{Log}(u)=\ln(\mid u\mid)+i\operatorname{atan2}(\Im(u),\Re(u)).$$

And finally [$\operatorname{atan2}$ is defined as](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2)

[image]

So the complex angle in the OP's case would be a complex number:

$$\operatorname{arccos}\left(\frac{5+6i}{4\sqrt{7}}\right).$$

Comment: OK, but is that really the way to define the angle between two vectors in a complex inner product space?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know. But I saw that something analogue to the angle could be calculated. I cannot intuit this angle between conplex matrice5s. I just hoped that you knew why you tried to compute such things.